# Disabling style of other divs when cliking new one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a "music machine", but i face problem i haven't been able to solve. All the other parts of the music machine work well. Only i want that if you click on (or press corresponding key) new music-pad, the last one "dis-activates" its style. Etc only the sound that is currently playing has active-pad.

I have tried this and several other examples.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
      var audioDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("clip");
      for (var i = 0, len = audioDiv.length; i < len; i++) {
        audioDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = "Grey";
        audioDiv[i].style.margin = "50px"
        }
    }, true)
```

This is the SoundPad part of the code

```
class SoundPad extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      padStyle: inactiveStyle,
      toPlay: true,
    };
    this.playSound = this.playSound.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.padControl = this.padControl.bind(this);
    this.stopOther = this.stopOther.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
    document.addEventListener("play", this.stopOther, true);
    document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
      var audioDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("clip");
      for (var i = 0, len = audioDiv.length; i < len; i++) {
        audioDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = "Grey";
        audioDiv[i].style.margin = "50px"
        }
    }, true)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
    document.removeEventListener("play", this.stopOther, true);
    document.removeEventListener("pause", function(){
      var audioDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("clip");
      for (var i = 0, len = audioDiv.length; i < len; i++) {
        audioDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = "Grey";
        audioDiv[i].style.margin = "50px"
        }
    }, true)
  }

  handleKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === this.props.keyCode) {
      this.playSound();
    }
  }

  playSound(e) {
    if (this.state.toPlay) {
      const sound = document.getElementById(this.props.keyTrigger);
      sound.currentTime = 0;
      sound.play();
      this.padControl();
      this.props.changeDisplay(this.props.clipName);
    } else {
      const sound = document.getElementById(this.props.keyTrigger);
      sound.currentTime = 0;
      sound.pause();
      this.padControl();
      this.props.changeDisplay(String.fromCharCode(160));
    }
  }

  padControl() {
    this.state.toPlay
      ? this.setState({
          padStyle: activeStyle,
          toPlay: !this.state.toPlay
        })
      : this.setState({
          padStyle: inactiveStyle,
          toPlay: !this.state.toPlay
        });
  }

  stopOther(e) {
        var audios = document.getElementsByClassName("clip");
        for (var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (audios[i] != e.target) {
            audios[i].pause();
          } 
        }
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="drum-pad"
        id={this.props.clipId}
        onClick={this.playSound}
        style={this.state.padStyle}
      >
        <audio
          className="clip"
          id={this.props.keyTrigger}
          src={this.props.clip}
        />
        {this.props.keyTrigger}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
const inactiveStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "Grey",
  margin: "50px"
};

const activeStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "Blue",
  margin: "40px"
};
```

full code: https://codepen.io/mathiascoding/pen/GaZxgr?editors=1010

Would appreciate if the solution would be in JS not JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a simple snippet with the logic you are looking for:

```js
for (var el of document.getElementsByClassName('box')) {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var activeEl = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0]
    if (activeEl) activeEl.classList.remove('active')
    e.target.classList.add('active')
  })
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.active {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

On each button click, you want to find all elements with the `active` class and remove them, and then apply the `active` class to the element you just clicked. You could technically achieve this using style, but classes are much much easier to use.

EDIT: After looking through your codepen, this code should work fine:

```js
const inactiveStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "Grey",
  margin: "50px"
};

const activeStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "Blue",
  margin: "40px"
};

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // If the element clicked has the class drum-pad
  if (e.target.classList.contains('drum-pad')) {
    // then get all the elements with the class drum-pad
    var drumPads = document.getElementsByClassName('drum-pad')
    // For each drum-pad
    for (var drumPad of drumPads) {
      // Loop over the keys in inactiveStyle
      Object.keys(inactiveStyle).map(key => {
        // and apply it to the element
        drumPad.style[key] = inactiveStyle[key]
      })
    }
    // Then loop over the keys in active style
    Object.keys(activeStyle).map(key => {
      // and apply it to the click element
      e.target.style[key] = activeStyle[key]
    })
  }

})
```

```html
<div id="Music-Bank">
  <!-- react-text: 11 -->
  <!-- /react-text -->
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Pair-Of-Dice" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="Q" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/u32apb7wl4z0abr/Ti%C3%ABsto%20%20Allure%20-%20Pair%20Of%20Dice%20%28Radio%20Edit%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 14 -->Q
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Speechless" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="W" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/rirdacgv842n19z/Robin%20Schulz%20feat.%20Erika%20Sirola%20-%20Speechless%20%28Lyrics%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 17 -->W
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Sunset-Love" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="E" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ncv727qclyg0e5l/PETIT%20BISCUIT%20-%20Sunset%20Lover.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 20 -->E
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Lets-Go-Home" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="A" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nixax61siercuzm/Eklo%20-%20Lets%20Go%20Home%20%28Sinco%20Remix%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 23 -->A
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Are-You-With-Me" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="S" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9hruu7ag6nk5e49/Lost%20Frequencies%20-%20Are%20You%20With%20Me%20%28Kungs%20Remix%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 26 -->S
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Fallen" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="D" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/8np1rhnfutwyimw/KLYMVX%20feat.%20COZY%20-%20Fallen%20%28Kygo%20Rework%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 29 -->D
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Swing" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="Z" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4c2ypp31ofdjbjl/Danny%20Ocean%20-%20Swing%20%28Letra%20%20Lyrics%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 32 -->Z
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Otro Trago" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="X" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vu8u5qntv9qhfzf/Sech%20%20Darell%20-%20%20Otro%20Trago%28LETRA%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 35 -->X
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div class="drum-pad" id="Mi Error" style="background-color: blue; margin: 40px;"><audio class="clip" id="C" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xeoceqaj9vyizxm/Eladio%20Carrion%20Ft%20Zion%20-%20Mi%20Error%20%28Letra%29.mp3?dl=0" style="background-color: grey; margin: 50px;"></audio>
    <!-- react-text: 38 -->C
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <!-- react-text: 39 -->
  <!-- /react-text -->
</div>
```

Comment: Code is good, but i would also need that the pads act on the same way when pressing corresponding keys. And i also noticed the weird thing that sometimes it takes double-click to activate music, etc with first click activates pad, and with second click starts the music.

Comment: I saw that you placed my code in each of the drum pads. This is a bad idea, since it creates a listener for each drumpad. This is not what you want. You would want to place my code in your app class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Kobe is correctly, but the React has your own way to manipulate the DOM, and isn't recommended to use `document`, instead of you can use `React.createRef()` or `useRef()` with hooks. You find the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.
>
> In the typical React dataflow, props are the only way that parent components interact with their children. To modify a child, you re-render it with new props. However, there are a few cases where you need to imperatively modify a child outside of the typical dataflow. The child to be modified could be an instance of a React component, or it could be a DOM element. For both of these cases, React provides an escape hatch.

Comment: I agree, but the way OP is already handling their code, using a ref now won't help. If they were to use refs from the very start, I would've written an example tailored to it :)

Comment: Of course, I also agree, but I am complementing your response in case someone in the future sees your answer and maybe assisting the OP in future projects.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to achieve the desire behavior by providing additional props from your `SoundPadSide` parent component to you child `SoundPad` components.

My idea is to control `SoundPad` active state from it's parent component `SoundPadSide`.

Basically you need to define `state` in your `SoundPadSide` component to control what is active at the moment.

Then you need to define a callback function which will change active Pad:

```js
class SoundPadSide extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeSoundPadId: "Speechless"
    };
    this.handleActiveChanged = this.handleActiveChanged.bind(this);
  }

  handleActiveChanged(id) {
    this.setState({ activeSoundPadId: id });
  }
}
```

In constructor you can define the initial state for `activeSoundPadId`. For example I took the second from your music list.

next you need to pass these properties to your `SoundPad` components in `render()` method:

```js
MusicBank = this.props.musicData.map((Obj, i, MusicArr) => {
    return (
      <SoundPad
        clipId={MusicArr[i].id}
        clip={MusicArr[i].url}
        keyCode={MusicArr[i].keyCode}
        keyTrigger={MusicArr[i].keyTrigger}
        clipName={MusicArr[i].clipName}
        changeDisplay={this.props.changeDisplay}
        power={this.props.power}

        isActive={this.state.activeSoundPadId === MusicArr[i].id}
        activate={this.handleActiveChanged}
      />
    );
  }
```

There are a couple of changes in `SoundPad` components. As it now receives additional props than we should apply them.
I call `activate` callback in your `palySound`method if current `SoundPad`y is not active:

```js
playSound(e) {
   this.props.activate(this.props.clipId);

   if (this.state.toPlay) {
      const sound = document.getElementById(this.props.keyTrigger);
      sound.currentTime = 0;
      sound.play();
      this.padControl();
      this.props.changeDisplay(this.props.clipName);
    } else {      
      const sound = document.getElementById(this.props.keyTrigger);
      sound.currentTime = 0;
      sound.pause();
      this.padControl();
      this.props.changeDisplay(String.fromCharCode(160));
}
```

One more change in `SoundPad` `render()` method:

```js
    return (
      <div
        class="Inactive"
        className="drum-pad"
        id={this.props.clipId}
        onClick={this.playSound}

        style={this.props.isActive ? activeStyle : inactiveStyle}
      >
      ...
```

I have updated your code a little. [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOXdjz?editors=1011) you can find demo